# USB retransmits SET_CONFIGURATION request

Tags: debugging, arm, usb

I connected NanoPi Neo(Linux) as a USBProxy device between host(Windows) and printer. There is flow from the bootUp [Wireshark flow](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8m1Ip.png)

After that transmission stops. SET_CONFIGURATION config value is 1, printer responds with empty data. There is no single error response. Could someone say based on flow, is it correctly or not?

When printer and hosts are connected directly, communication works fine and printer is detected correctly. I also checked it with different hosts (Windows and Linux) and it also worked as expected.

Comment: You haven't said where the trace is.  Is it PC -> NanoPi or NanoPi->printer?  Probably the first.  So there can be errors on the Pi to printer side.  Does the proxy have a way to dump?  Or you could try `tcpdump -i usbmonX` on the Pi and then import to wireshark.

Comment: I grabbed logs with tcpdump usbmon0 (all buses), and there is result https://imgur.com/a/ARsMJGZ